ANALYZE TABLE .. COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS ... doesn't save per-partition statistics
I am using Apache Spark and parquet-based external tables created via
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} ({columns}) USING PARQUET {part_clause} LOCATION '{path}'
Tables are partitioned (2-level partitions). So far so good.
Some of columns have very limited range of values per partition (partitions are monthly, so can contain only 30 days of timestamps in column 'created_at' for example).
I assumed that Spark can use partition column statistics (min/max values) to skip useless partitions in SELECT queries, even if partitioning column is not part of WHERE clause.
I tried to run
analyze table T compute statistics for columns created_at;
or
analyze table T partition (part = 'foo', ymd = '2024-01-01') compute statistics for columns created_at; 
and checked query like
select 
    count(*)
    , min(created_at)
    , max(created_at)
    , max(uuid)
from T
where 
    part = 'foo'
    and created_at >= '2024-01-12'
    and created_at < '2024-01-13'
;

over dataset of several years. My expectation was that it will automatically pick partition with ymd='2024-01-01' based on column min/max values.
But query still scans whole dataset (based on WebUI).
If I add explicit partitioning column condition, it works as expected (much faster by skipping other partitions).
I checked metastore DB, it contains column min/max value per table T, in "TABLE_PARAMS" table, looks like this:
    178 | spark.sql.statistics.colStats.created_at.distinctCount            | 181232123
    178 | spark.sql.statistics.colStats.created_at.min                      | 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000
    178 | spark.sql.statistics.colStats.created_at.nullCount                | 0
    178 | spark.sql.statistics.colStats.created_at.avgLen                   | 8
    178 | spark.sql.statistics.numRows                                      | 181245643
    178 | spark.sql.statistics.colStats.created_at.max                      | 2024-08-20 13:59:28.000000
    178 | spark.sql.statistics.colStats.created_at.version                  | 2
    178 | spark.sql.statistics.colStats.created_at.maxLen                   | 8

However table "PARTITION_PARAMS" contains no useful information for my partition in question, only totalSize and numFiles.
Table "PART_COL_STATS" has 0 rows.
I tried both direct connection from Spark to metastore DB, and use of Hive Metastore Server (HMS).

Spark version: 3.4.1
Hive package version: 3.1.3
Hive metastore version (table "VERSION"): 3.1.0

Please help me see what do I miss, why partition statistics are not collected.

What does DESCRIBE EXTENDED T PARTITION (part = 'foo', ymd = '2024-01-01') show?

it shows table schema, then # Detailed Partition Information 

partition values (same as in query)
data location
Partition Parameters: {transient_lastDdlTime=1726705484, totalSize=467937755, numFiles=3}

None of this seems sufficient for the purpose I mentioned above - skipping unneeded partitions.
More - I checked other tables which had no ANALYZE, they show similar data, so it is not result of the ANALYZE.
